# Where query in both relationships Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

How can I get **all users** which names starts with the given string, and also where their **city** from **profile** relationship is equal to **London**?

`$users = User::where('name', 'LIKE', "{$searchingName}%")->with('profile')->get();`

Comment: Use the `whereHas()` function: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence. `whereHas('profile', function($subQuery){ return $subQuery->where('city', 'London'); })` (assuming `city` is column and not another relationship.)

Answer (score 0):

You may find [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) very useful:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

// Retrieve profiles where the city is like 'London'.
$users = User::where('name', 'LIKE', "{$searchingName}%")
              ->whereHas('profile', function (Builder $query) {
                   $query->where('city', 'like', 'London');
              })->get();
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the exactly same thing. But got unexpected error. And now I saw im missing ->  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
It works.